# Why do translate3d animations pause for ease timer functions?

Tags: css, animation

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XyvV/9/).

I'm using translate3d transformations with a timer function of 'ease':

```
@keyframes anim {
    from {
        transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
        transform:translate3d(100px, 100px,-100px);
    }
    to {
        transform:translate3d(200px, 200px, 0px);
    }
}
```

Why is it not a continuous animation, instead of pausing in the middle? This only happens when using ease-* as the timer function. Is this intended behaviour? If so, how can I make it a continuous animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an animation using keyframes, the timing function is applied to **every** transition between keyframes.

You can set the timing function at the keyframe, or at the animation; that doesn't change the fact that those are separate functions.

That means that there is not a function that can achieve *ease* for the **full** animation easily.  (it is fun that it is not easy to get *ease* :-) )

Since you have only two transitions (3 keyframes), however, an approximate alternative is to set ease-in for the first transition, and ease-out for the second.

For three transitions, the one in the middle would be *linear*

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 100px,-100px);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(200px, 200px, 0px);
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XyvV/10/)

Notice that there is no timing function to be applied to the last keyframe, because that is applied to the interval and not to the keyframe.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this intended behavior?

Yes, that's how the `ease-*` timing function(s) are suppose to work.

Here is a visual taken from this [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#Keywords_for_common_timing-functions) on animation timing functions.

> [image]

`ease` represents the timing function `cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0)`

> How can I make it a continuous animation?

Use `linear`, which represents the timing function `cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)`

> [image]

Updated CSS

```
#a {
    animation: anim 1s linear infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4f95/)

Comment: Josh I've accepted Vals' answer because he goes into detail about why it behaves that way and offers a way to do exactly what I wanted to do.